# Webform file upload field replacing existing file in directory in drupal

Tags: 7, webforms

I have created Webform in Drupal in the following fields

1. Name   - Text field
2. Age    - Text field
3. Picture - File field

when uploading user file in the file field, the file name is photo.jpg again the another user uploading file in the file field the file name is called photo.jpg. The file location directory is replacing into photo_0.jpg but this value is not updating in the database.

while I am selecting this data from database the photo is changing i.e i am getting different file for different user. What should i do for this? please give me any solution.